# how to count leading 0 in vector

Tags: vhdl

```
 back:while (sub1_mantissa(52)='0') loop
      sub1_mantissa := sub1_mantissa(51 downto 0) & '0';
      count := count + "000000000001";
 end loop back;
```

hi .i want to count leading zeros in vector...like if my result is 0001 so it will show 3 zeros..so my counter will be increment by 3..and when i will get the first 1 in msb then my loop will stop...

i m using the above code..but it is not working...counter value it takes is too large like 1100111...i am not getting where is d problem...guys plz help me...n reply soon

Comment: as I understand you don't get the expected results. however, the code you posted should basically work; you should post the complete code to let us reproduce the issue! one comment up front: if your vector "sub1_mantissa" contains only '0's, you'll have an infinite loop! avoid that!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a for loop to count this, something like this:

```
  variable zero_count : natural := 0;
  for i in sub1_mantissa'range loop
    if sub1_mantissa(i) = '0' then
      zero_count := zero_count + 1;
    else
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;
```

NOTE: this will only count the leading zeros if sub1_mantissa is declared using DOWNTO notation.